# How ISP read HTTPS headers

Tags: http, https, http-headers, wireshark

**In my country, we have special data add-on packages on the internet packages. Like zoom, teams data packages and WhatsApp, facebook packages. I heard before ISP read our HTTP headers and identify whether
where is our data packet going and not reading TCP destination IP.
and some people are spoofing HTTPS traffic by injecting

1. X-onlinehost
2. x-forward-host
3. x-forwarded-for

these headers to take advantages of these addons packages.
My question is if HTTPS is encrypted, then how ISP read these custom HTTPS headers?
Another question is if ISP can read HTTPS headers also I can read HTTPS headers in my LAN network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man-in-the-Middle (MITM) attack which implies the ability of your adversary to generate certificates for a given website that is trusted by your browser.  This implies the ability to actively change your network traffic.  Anything, particular JavaScript such as advertisement, on the pages you visit.  HTTPS doesn't encrypt DNS (or of course HTTP) traffic.

ISP cannot read your LAN traffic, unless, they happen to have a device like their complementary router on your LAN. VPNs and software designed to look at content like virus scanners are also suspect.  Again, anything on the pages you visit, is still a valid attack.